# How to call the Edit method from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am a beginner in ASP .NET MVC4 RAZOR, I created an application with:

- Business objet class library,
- DAL class library(using LINQ to SQL with stored procedure),
- Business Layer and WCF hosting to IIS 8.0 and generate a proxyclient.

My object is `PersonBO` and I called it in my controller side with the generated proxy `PersonClient`, I am trying to create a `Edit` method but I don't know how to call it, here is the code I tried in controller side:

```
private ActionResult Edit(PersonBO objPerson)
{
  Int32 idRet = -1;
  try
  {
    using (PersonClient PClient = new PersonClient())
    {
      idRet = JClient.UpdatePerson(objPerson.Id,
        objPerson.Name,
        objPerson.LastName,
        objPerson.BirthdayDate);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception) 
  { 
    throw;
  }    
  return View(objPerson);
}
```

Here is the `Edit` to call:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Int32 id)
{
  PersonBO objPerson=new PersonBO ();
  using (PersonClient Jclient = new PersonClient())
  {
    if ((ModelState.IsValid))
    {
      objPerson= Jclient.GetPersonById(id);
      Edit(objPerson);
      return RedirectToAction("GetAll");
    }
    else
    {
      return View(objPerson);
    }
  }
}
```

Can somebody help please, I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the problem coming?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up you GET and POST methods. Your GET method would normally have parameter `int ID` which gets the person with the ID and returns a view to edit that person. Your POST method would have  parameter `PersonBO objPerson` which is populated when you post back (and then save to the database and redirect, or return the view if `ModelState` is not valid)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your private method to something else, for example EditPerosn to prevent misunderstanding, and change it return value to void or something else except ActionResult
Your code should look something like this:

```
private Int32 EditPerson(PersonBO objPerson)
{
  Int32 idRet = -1;
  try
  {
    using (PersonClient PClient = new PersonClient())
    {
      idRet = JClient.UpdatePerson(objPerson.Id,
        objPerson.Name,
        objPerson.LastName,
        objPerson.BirthdayDate);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception) 
  { 
  }    
  return idRet;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PersonBO objPerson)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && objPerson != null)
    {
        Int32 result = EditPerson(objPerson);
        if(result != -1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetAll");
        }
        else 
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Update failed!";
            return View(objPerson);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Validation error!";
        return View(objPerson);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 2 methods to do this:
1. To get the PersonBO and render the view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Int32 id)
{
  PersonBO objPerson = null;
  using (PersonClient Jclient = new PersonClient())
  {
      objPerson= Jclient.GetPersonById(id);
  }
  if (objPerson != null) 
  {
     return View(objPerson);
  } else {
     return View("NotFound");
  }
}
```

2. To save posted changes:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Edit(PersonBO objPerson)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       { 
          return View(objPerson);
       }
       using (PersonClient PClient = new PersonClient())
       {
            idRet = JClient.UpdatePerson(objPerson.Id,
                                         objPerson.Name,
                                         objPerson.LastName,
                                         objPerson.BirthdayDate);
       }
   }
   ```

It's just a simplified example to give an idea. Add Exceptions handling/logging if you can/wish to handle them somehow.